# Падеж слов "должностные лица"

Tags: падежи, грамматика

Государственные органы и должностные лица, указанные в статье 5 закона, следует рассматривать в качестве органов дознания — в каком падеже поставить слова «должностные лица» и «указанные» (в именительном или родительном)?

Comment: Извините, отвечу вопросом на вопрос. А можно ли должностных лиц назвать органами дознания? 

Comment: А может, поменять местами эти объекты? Тогда не будет претензий ни к органам, ни к падежам.
 "Должностных лиц и государственные органы, указанные в статье 5 закона, следует рассматривать в качестве органов дознания".

Comment: Нет, все равно коряво. Несогласованность двух компонент. Мне понравился вариант, предложенные @behemothus.

Answer (score 2):

Я правильно понимаю, что речь идёт о винительном падеже, который может совпадать  с именительным или родительным - в зависимости от одушевлённости объекта?

Вообще вопрос этот неожиданно сложный. Лучше всего избегать подобных формулировок вообще. Но если уж никак без этого, то давайте разбираться от печки.

Л**и**ца в данном значении - сущствительное одущевленное ("рассматривать должностных лиц, упоминаемых..."), органы, пусть и государственные, - неодушевленное ("рассматривать  органы, упоминаемые..."), имеет место грамматическая несочетаемость. В таких случаях Розенталь рекомендует ориентироваться на последнюю составляющую, т.е. на одушевлённость "лиц". Но в нашем случае этот путь спорен, поскольку создает двусмысленность: можно понять так, что  "указанные в статье" относится только к последней части, т.е. к лицам, но не к органам. Тем не менее, я не вижу другого пути, как оставить форму "одушевленного винительного".

*Государственные органы и должностных лиц, указанных в статье 5 закона, следует рассматривать в качестве органов дознания.*

Но, повторюсь, лучше семь раз подумать, нельзя ли переделать фразу.

~~~~ 25.08.2012

> А если переделать так: Государственные органы и должностных лиц, которые указаны в статье 5 закона, следует рассматривать в качестве органов дознания.
> ([[@жанна](/users/476/%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0)](/users/476/%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0))

Нет, ну это-то ничего не решает, все равно несогласованность. Не говоря уж о том, что это против рекомендаций Розенталя (и не только). Если "должностных лиц", то должно быть "указанных". Нет, тут действительно нужна переделка всей фразы. Там в "статье 5" действительно указаны и органы, и лица?

Кстати, если вы уж придерживаетесь юридического языка, то, наверное, не "указанных", а "поименовынных", нет? И что такое "следует рассматривать"? Дайте контекст, может, попонятнее будет. Пока я в меру своего понимания сказал бы как-то так:

*Государственные органы и должностные лица, указанные в статье 5 закона, (законодательно) рассматриваются как органы дознания.* 
Или (в зависимости от смысла):
*Государственные органы и должностные лица, указанные в статье 5 закона, наделяются полномочиями органов дознания.*

Comment: А если переделать так: Государственные органы и должностных лиц, которые указаны в статье 5 закона, следует рассматривать в качестве органов дознания.

Comment: в тексте ответил

Answer (score 0):

В винительном (*рассматривать что? органы, кого? лиц*). Существительное **органы** - неодушевленное. Следовательно винительный совпадает с именительным. Существительное **лица** в значении "люди" является одушевленным. Здесь винительный совпадает с родительным (но все же это не родительный падеж!). Родительный здесь неуместен. 
Что касается причастия **указанные**, что его форма должна совпадать с ближайшим к нему определяемым словом (это существительное *лица*). 
В результате получится: *Государственные органы и должностных лиц, указанных в статье 5 закона, следует рассматривать в качестве органов дознания*.

Comment: @olsa, проблема тут не с органами, а с лицами...

Comment: Дополняю свой ответ!

Answer (score 0):

КМК, "государственные органы и должностные лица" здесь нужно рассматривать как цельную фразу. И вот вся эта фраза целиком - в винительном падеже. Видимо, именно так она и была указана в упомянутой 5-й статье. Поскольку фраза эта взята из нормативного акта, изменение на "наделяются полномочиями органов дознания" может привести к искажению смысла. А "рассматривать должностных лиц" - вообще извращение какое-то.

Comment: >изменение на "наделяются полномочиями органов дознания" может привести к искажению смысла    

-?  
  
>А "рассматривать должностных лиц" - вообще извращение какое-то.  
  
-???

Comment: @behemothus, Вам юмор не нравится? Действительно, не каждое должностное лицо захочет, чтобы его рассматривали )))   

Кстати, видела вывеску на банке: "Вход для юридических лиц". На полном серьезе! Так и представила, как они идут, "лица" эти )))

Comment: Я не вижу юмора. Должностное, физическое, юридическое лицо - обычный оборот, не несущий подтекста. Или у меня уже "глаз замылился"...   
Вот "вход для юрлиц" - это уже достойно рассмотрения. Но ттолько потому что в даненом контексте применение термина не уместно. Хотя, с дугой стороны, как еще сказать-то? Для "представителей"? Не совсем то... раз ве что "по вопросам обслуживания..." Но тогда "вход по воросам" само по себе может "рассматриваться". )))
Впроцем по сравнению с "ногами (а то и мордой) лица кавказской национальности" все это даже рядои не стоит.

Comment: Да, действительно, "представителей юрлиц" - было бы еще корявей. Так, как есть, вполне хорошо: все понятно. Но все равно весело. )))